# Как убрать слово из строки PHP?

Tags: php

Необходимо убрать слово+символ "- Неисправности" из генерации тега посредством PHP.
Товарищи-вебмастеры, как можно это осуществить?

```html
<h1><?php echo $this->product->product_name ?> - <?php echo $categoryName ?></h1>
```

Comment: Не вижу такого слова "неисправности". Там имя продукта - категория.

Comment: @An0ther0ne это слово является результатом выполнения второй части кода. "Неисправности" - это название родительской категории товара.

Comment: @An0ther0ne необходимо, чтобы именно эта категория не добавлялась в заголовок

Comment: Тогда конкретизируйте задачу: требуется убрать вывод категорий продуктов вообще или подавить вывод продуктов категория которых "Неисправности" ?

Comment: @ второй вариант: подавить вывод слова "Неисправности" в тег <h1>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По второму варианту:

```
<h1><?php echo $this->product->product_name;
if (strcmp($categoryName,'Неисправности')!=0){ 
    echo ' - '.$categoryName; 
}?></h1>
```

Comment: А можно прописать два значения, через запятую, например?

Comment: какие два значения

Comment: если например, в дальнейшем потребуется убрать два значения, которые следует удалить из строки

Comment: то добавите это условие (в strcmp()) через 'or' или опишете выражением regex чтобы охватить все ваши варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Немного костыльный вариант:

```
<h1><?php echo $this->product->product_name ?> <?php echo ($categoryName !== 'Неисправности') ? "- $categoryName" : '' ?></h1>
```